# How to fix 'ECONNREFUSED' error in my nodejs app using docker?

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using Docker container for my node app which is a REST API Server. It use multiple backend (currently mongoDB and mysql). My mongoclient is connecting to the port defined in my docker-compose.yml but my mysql is not configuring to it, throwing ECONNREFUSED error.
Also i like to add In my localhost I have both mongodb and mysql installed on my system.
Below is the code of my `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml`

```
FROM node:8
RUN mkdir -p /home/sharad/eapp
WORKDIR /home/sharad/eapp
COPY package.json /home/sharad/eapp/
RUN npm install
COPY . /home/sharad/eapp
EXPOSE 8016
CMD [ "npm","start" ]
```

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  server:
    image: sharadm20/eyantra-app
    restart: always

    ports:
      - 8016:8016

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    links:
      - mongo  
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: secret
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ENABLE_ADMIN: 'true'
  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8082:8080
```

And below is the error which I am encountering:

```
Unable to connect to the mysql database: { SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306 }
```

Comment: Fix the hostname or poet, or start the database.

Comment: I have changed the port name in the config file. That doesn't work.Also I am using Adminer which uses mysql and it is getting connected.

Comment: try connecting to db:3306 instead of localhost:3306, docker containers are independent and need their host names to see each other, even if they are exposing the port to the host, also you'll have to add a link from db to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by changing the Hostname in mysql config to the name similar to docker image name( in my case mysql is called db) so the hostname+port would look like db:3306.

Thanks to Marc Sances for pointing it out.